# usage of comma before time phrase

Tags: punctuation

> 1. A shrine was built on Singuttra Hill by the decision of King Okkalapa over 2,500 years ago.
> 2. A shrine was built on Singuttra Hill by the decision of King Okkalapa, over 2,500 years ago.

I think the sentence would be clear if I put comma before the time phrase "over 2,500 years ago."

Answer (score 2):

The comma there is not *incorrect* but it is unnecessary.  Most readers would not misunderstand what you are trying to say.

However the phrase "by the decision of King Okkalapa" is awkward.  Kings make decisions, yes, but then they issue [*decrees*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decree) to tell people what they want done.

> A shine was built there over 2500 years ago by *royal decree* of King Okkalapa.

Although I would prefer not to use the passive voice:

> Over 2500 years ago, King Okkalapa *decreed* that a shrine be built there.

If you prefer you may use "order" or "command" (or another synonym) instead of "decree".

Answer (score 1):

You don't usually put a comma before such time phrases or adverbials when they come at the end of a sentence  However, you usually use a comma after them when they come at the beginning of a sentence, for example:

Over 2500 years ago, a shrine was built....